# is there any benchmarks for large data containers?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, large-data

i'm currently looking for a way to handle large data set.

it seems stxxl is frequently recommended solution, 
however i need to know more about it, before making a decision.

the question is

1. Is STXXL completely platform neutral?
2. Any alternatives?
3. Any benchmarks about large data library?

Comment: How large is large?

Comment: The [STXXL publication](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/dementiev/files/TRKA2005_18.pdf) contains some benchmark data. However, I have to say that I’m missing a scalability analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I have personally tried it on both Windows and Linux, and there is no reason why it should not compile on Mac. I do not know what you mean by **neutral** though.

2) There are alternatives like TPIE, LEDA-SM etc. which are not developed anymore. I think STXXL is your best bet as it supports PDM (Parallel Disk Model).

Comment: @GManNickG 2GB ~ 50GB? focus on this question is 'Which container shows a best performance, in case that, a data set requires x2 ~ x5 of main memory(4GB~16GB)', and a scalability to cover even 1TB~ is secondary issue. a benchmark what i meant for was comparison among number of very recent libraries.(it seems there are not much alternatives...) 1) 'neutral' means 'platform independent' and your answer was sufficient enough for my question. thx! 2) it seems stxxl is widely accepted.